# Error: has stopped unexpectedly. please try again - Android

Tags: java, android

I wonder what is the reason of this error happen...

I was developing a CRUD and for some reason burst it. Many codes and take you to analyze, is there anything I can do to know where this error is being triggered

[image: Folders]

**MainActivity.java**

```
package br.com.crud.Activitys;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import br.com.crud.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    Button btnView;
    Button btnCadastro;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnCadastro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastro);
        btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);

        btnView.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){

            }
        });

        btnCadastro.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NovoProdutoActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NovoProdutoActivity.java**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package br.com.crud.Activitys;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.com.crud.R;

/**
 *
 * @author muky
 */
public class NovoProdutoActivity extends Activity{

    Button btnSalvar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.novo_produto);


        btnSalvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSalvar);

        btnSalvar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Produto Salvo com Sucesso", 6).show();
            }
        });

    }



}
```

**LogCat**

[image]

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="br.com.crud"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- View Cadastro de Produto -->
        <activity
            android:name="NovoProdutoActivity"
            android:label="NovoProduto"/>

         <!-- View Listar Produtos -->
         <activity
             android:name="ListaProdutoActivity"
             android:label="ListarProdutos"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Take a look at the logcat. Please post it here if you would like some help. Also, post your code.

Comment: Ok, i'll upload my codes

Comment: Why God, why are they giving me -1? -.-"

Comment: Can you also post your AndroidManifest.xml? You're getting a ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Your main activity in code is `br.com.crud.Activitys.MainActivity` while the manifest says it is `br.com.crud.MainActivity`. Make sure the full class names agree in manifest and in code.